# All asmx web services stop working with a port in the url

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

We have some asmx webservices that are hosted on a local server e.g http:// 192. 168.180. 102/webservice.asmx

However when these are hosted in IIS with another a port or alias e.g

```
http:// 192. 168.180. 102:8000/webservice.asmx
or http://somehostname:8000/webservice.asmx
```

..then all the web services on the server just stop working returning 404 errors, however all the other aspx pages work fine. Is there something I'm missing here?

Also if it helps, the .asmx is not hosted separately in IIS, its inside a web application which is hosted in IIS.

This is what the windows error shows for each request made to any aspx page trying to connect to any asmx web service:

Exception type: WebException 
Exception message: The remote name could not be resolved

Its so weird, because its hosted on the same setup!

Comment: You've added another site in IIS, listening on port 8000, and deployed your WebServices to this site, right?

Comment: Hi @nonnb, yes thats correct. So lots of aspx pages and a few asmx on the same IIS site. Works fine without a port, doesn't with a port. All the same handlers and mappings in web.config and IIS and its all the default settings that I have used.